# Using Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to use Apache Drill. The instructions at https://drill.apache.org/docs/drill-in-10-minutes/ seem to be very straightforward but after following them I get the following error:

```
show files;
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: SHOW FILES is supported in workspace type schema only. Schema [] is not a workspace schema.
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing config for the path to files maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are issuing this command without connecting to any schema. You can issue this command after switching to particular schema using 'use '.Issue 'show schemas' to list available schemas.

If you are using sqlline, You may specify schema while connecting to sqlline as below (to connect schema 'dfs') .

```
sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:schema=dfs;zk=<zk node>:<zk port>"
```